# Why did Gautam Buddha marry his cousin , when cousin marriage is banned in Hinduism?

Tags: marriage, other-religions, buddhism

Siddharth was born in a Hindu family.

Siddharth Gautam Marriage was arrange marriage with his cousin.

But as much as i know cousin marriage is banned in Hinduism

Comment: because he was Shakyamuni.

Comment: Maybe he loved her.

Comment: His cousin? Do you mean niece?

Comment: Yasodharā (who married Siddhārtha who went on to become the Buddha) and Devadatta were children of Suppabuddha. Suppabuddha was Siddhārtha’s uncle, being the brother of the sisters Māya (Siddhartha’s birth mother) and Pajāpatī ( his stepmother who actually raised him after Māya died at childbirth ). Marrying within the family was common in many parts of the ancient world.

Comment: the word 'cousin' is very diluted to mean any relation. But there is a BIG difference between paternal and maternal cousins. You're only allowed to marry non-sagotra 'mother's brother's or father's sisters' cousins - because their gotra is different. Turushka (Turks, the ancient name for Muslims) - marry even paternal cousin, like father's brothers daughter, which is prohibited everywhere in India. @KauvaAatma

Comment: @CR241, see above

Comment: I did not know that ram thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

Customs will keep on changing with times.

Marriages between cousins may not be prevalent in present times in Northern parts of India.  However, it is an accepted form in Southern parts of India.

Even in Northern parts of India marriages between cousins was order of the day in ancient times.

In Mahabharata there was a mention of [Kunti, sister of Vasudeva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01112.htm) and paternal aunt of Krishna.

> There was amongst the Yadavas a chief named Sura. He was the father of
>   Vasudeva. And he had a daughter called Pritha, who was unrivalled for
>   beauty on earth. And, O thou of Bharata's race, Sura, always truthful
>   in speech, gave from friendship this his firstborn daughter unto his
>   childless cousin and friend, the illustrious Kuntibhoja--the son of
>   his paternal aunt--pursuant to a former promise.

So Pritha, who was brought up by Kuntibhoja, was known as Kunti.  She got married to King Pandu and Arjuna was her son.

Subhadra was the sister of Sri Krishna, and thus Arjuna and Subhadra were cousins.

Marriage between [Subhadra and Arjuna](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01222.htm) was accepted at that point of time.

---

So there is nothing wrong in the marriage of Siddhartha with his cousin.

Comment: yeah, what he said

Comment: the word 'cousin' is very diluted to mean any relation. But there is a BIG difference between 'paternal' and 'maternal' cousins. You're only allowed to marry non-sagotra cousins - 'mother's brother's son/daughter or father's sisters' son/daughter - because their GOTRA is different. Turushka (Turks, the ancient name for Muslims) - marry even paternal cousins, like father's brothers daughter, which is prohibited everywhere in India because they're like sisters.

Answer (score 2):

Cousin marriage is not banned.

Sa-Gotra cousin marriage is banned.

Your father's sister's daughter, or your mother's brother's daughter - belong to different gotra (that of their father's), so marriage between these type of first cousins is allowed.

But your father's brothers' daughter is same gotra as you, so she is like a sister, so that marriage is banned. This rule however, is not followed by Muslims. They inbreed.

You are probably used to the Western notion of the word 'cousin'. Since they don't give much importance to family relations, all types of cousins are grouped under cousins, while all type of uncles/aunts are grouped as Uncle/Aunt - no differentiation between mama or chacha or jija etc.